# Adding additional css attribute to particular modal class

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

How can i add a customize css for particular modal? There could be many modal, which defined in the class of modal. (For example: modal1, modal2, modal3, etc)
The modal-overlay class will be generated when the modal is clicked (materializecss framework)

```
<div id="modal3" class="modal modal3">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Congratulation</h4>
        <div class="row martop-20">
            <p>HQ1379622</p>
            <p>HQ1379622</p>
            <p>HQ1379622</p>
            <p>HQ1379622</p>
        </div>
        <a class="btn-grab btn-select-pop waves-effect" href="#modal1">OK</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-overlay" style="z-index: 1002; display: block; opacity: 0.5;"></div>
```

The modal-overlay will only be generated when the modal is active.

I need to change the background / some css for this particular modal-overlay.

[image: Output sample]

This is the output if the modal is show, and the modal-overlay will be removed when the modal is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#modal3 + .modal-overlay {
  background-color: #bada55;
}
```

It seems that the overlay always appears directly as next neighbor element of the modal. So just select the directly following `.modal-overlay` of the modal itself.

More infos about the [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see your modals and overlays are siblings therefore you could write a simple function like

```
function applyClassToOverlay(modalId, class) {
  var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);

  var modalOverlay = modal.nextElementSibling;

  modalOverlay.classList.add(class);
}
```

And deletion in way

```
function removeClassFromOverlay(modalId, class) {
  var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);

  var modalOverlay = modal.nextElementSibling;

  modalOverlay.classList.remove(class);
}
```

Another way if you need to customize a modal with specific `id`. You could simply write a CSS rule

```
#modal1 + .modal-overlay {
  // here goes the styling
}
```

And one more way what I can suggest out of screenshot. If we take the idea that modal-overlay is always `1` z-index behind the needed modal we can also access overlay that way

```
function applyClassToOverlay(modalId, class) {
  var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
  var modalZIndex - modal.style.zIndex;

  var modalOverlaysArr = [...document.qerySelectorAll('.modal-overlay')];

  var modalOverlay = modalOverlaysArr.find(overlay => overlay.style.zIndex === modalZIndex - 1);

  modalOverlay.classList.add(class);
}
```

Comment: @Quantastical I've written a solution to what the OP provided us with.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use JavaScript/jQuery. Assuming you've got some sort of function to open your modal, like an on click function...  you can hook into it to detect which modal is open.

With a simple if statement, we can detect if a certain modal is open (or rather has the class **.open**), if it returns true then we can do anything we like.

I'm using jQuery in this code for brevity.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){      
  if($('.modal3').is('.open')) {
    $('.modal-overlay').css('background', 'blue');
    $('.modal-overlay').addClass('newCSS');
  }
});
```

This is a starting point and with a bit of adaptation it should work in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a css that target the element you need. For example:

```
.modal-overlay{
    background-color: #bada55;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you need to affect only `modal3`, then change the css to

```
.modal3{
    background-color: #bada55;
}
```

if the `modal3` element is a descendent of `modal-overlay` than this should do the trick

```
.modal-overlay .modal3{
    background-color: #bada55;
}
```

Comment: But this will be affecting other modal. I need to have it for modal3 only

Comment: @Italy Gal, please check the updated question. the modal overlay is not within the modal3 block.